# How can I change the caption of a modal form without access to the source?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a third party component that displays a print preview form. I would like to change the caption of the preview form to something more appropriate. Unfortunately I do not have the source for the third party component and the component does not provide the functionality.

Is it possible to somehow catch the modal form as it is being displayed and set it's properties before it is shown?

Comment: Just another example of why you should never use third-party components for which you don't have the source if there's an option available to get it. :-) You might specify which third-party component you're using, so that if there's a known solution related to that component set someone can provide it.

Comment: @Ken: TeeChart. I could upgrade to the 'with source' version, but it's hard to justify a minimum of 250 dollars just to change the caption of a form :o)

Comment: The problem with that is if something changes (or they stop including TeeChart in the next version of Delphi), all of your code that uses it becomes unable to be moved to the next version of the compiler. If you have code that depends on third party components, you need to have the source to protect yourself in the future. It's one of the very first things you should learn after learning Delphi - it's open architecture is great for third party extensions, but using them w/o getting source cripples you when things change in the future and you can't fix issues yourself.

Comment: Hi Ken. I completely agree and own the source code for all the other components I use (around 7 or more). The reason I don't want to fork out for the TeeChart source is that it plays a very small part in the overall application and can easily be replaced if required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The modal form will cause the calling form to deactivate, you can listen for `WM_ACTIVATE` messages on the form that is active before the modal form is shown. You'll have the activating window's handle in the message handler, you can test that if it is of a form of the type of the modal form. Below example tests for the class name, which you can get with something like Spy++. Note that deactivation happens briefly after the modal form has become visible, but I don't think it would be possible to notice the differing caption.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  protected
    procedure WMActivate(var Message: TWMActivate); message WM_ACTIVATE;
  end;

procedure TForm1.WMActivate(var Message: TWMActivate);
var
  Form: TWinControl;
begin
  if Message.Active = WA_INACTIVE then begin
    Form := FindControl(Message.ActiveWindow);
    if Form is TCustomForm then begin
      if TCustomForm(Form).ClassName = 'TThirdPartyModalForm' then
        TCustomForm(Form).Caption := 'My caption';
    end;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: What about using the `TScreen.OnActiveFormChange` event with the `TScreen.ActiveCustomForm` or `TScreen.ActiveForm` property, instead of handling `WM_ACTIVATE` directly and searching for the active `TForm`?

Comment: @Remy - It is fired just a little bit later when the modal form is activated during the focus change, it should be fine. But FindControl is pretty fast if that's the concern, in fact it is called during Application.ProcessMessage with every queued message.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: `FindControl()` is fast because each `TWinControl` object stores its `Self` pointer inside its allocated `HWND` handle.  `FindControl()` is merely retreiving that pointer from the provided `HWND`. I was just thinking that the `TScreen` approach would be more VCL-like, and likely more crosss-platform, then resorting to handling platform-specific messages, that's all.

Comment: @Remy - Yep, I saw that point, your answer has my vote on it. :)

Answer (score 6):

Try using the `TScreen.OnActiveFormChange` event, using the `TScreen.ActiveCustomForm` or `TScreen.ActiveForm` property to know which `TForm` has the focus:

```
procedure TMainForm.DoSomething; 
begin 
  Screen.OnActiveFormChange := ActiveFormChanged;
  try
    // do something that triggers the modal form ...
  finally
    Screen.OnActiveFormChange := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.ActiveFormChanged(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TCustomForm;
begin
  Form := Screen.ActiveCustomForm; 
  if (Form <> nil) and (Form.ClassName = 'TModalFormClassName') then 
    Form.Caption := 'My caption'; 
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install a `WH_CBT` hook using the [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

```
var
 hhk: HHOOK;


function CBT_FUNC(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
const
  ClassNameBufferSize = 1024;
var
 hTemp  : HWND;
 i      : Integer;
 RetVal : Integer;
 ClassNameBuffer: Array[0..ClassNameBufferSize-1] of Char;
begin
   case nCode of
     HCBT_ACTIVATE:
     begin
       hTemp := HWND(wParam);
       if (Screen<>nil) and (hTemp>0) then
       begin
          RetVal := GetClassName(wParam, ClassNameBuffer, SizeOf(ClassNameBuffer));
          //check for the class 
          if (RetVal>0) and SameText(ClassNameBuffer,'TForm2') then
          begin
             Assert(RetVal < ClassNameBufferSize, 'Class name larger than fixed buffer size');
            for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount-1 do
             if Screen.Forms[i].Handle=hTemp then
               begin 
                  //set the caption
                  Screen.Forms[i].Caption:='Hello';
                  Break;
               end;
          end;
       end;
     end;
   end;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, lParam);
end;

Procedure InitHook();
var
  dwThreadID : DWORD;
begin
  dwThreadID := GetCurrentThreadId;
  hhk := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, @CBT_FUNC, hInstance, dwThreadID);
  if hhk=0 then RaiseLastOSError;
end;


Procedure KillHook();
begin
  if (hhk <> 0) then
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
end;


initialization
  InitHook();

finalization
  KillHook();
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a "pseudo" code you could try (not tested):

```
const
  MY_PRINT_PREVIEW_MSG = WM_USER + 200;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure MyPrintPreviewMsg(var Msg: TMessage); message MY_PRINT_PREVIEW_MSG;
    procedure MyPrintPreview;
  end;
...
procedure TForm1.MyPrintPreviewMsg(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  h: HWND;
begin
  h := Screen.Forms[0].Handle; // if the modal dialog is VCL dialog (verify it with spy++)
  // h := FindWindow(<class name>, <caption>); // non VCL window
  if (h <> 0) then
  begin
    SetWindowText(h, 'new caption');
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyPrintPreview;
begin
  PostMessage(Handle, MY_PRINT_PREVIEW_MSG, 0, 0);
  ThirdPartyPrintPreview;
end;
```